# using simple serverless python-requirements getting this error while deploy

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda, deployment, serverless

```
× Stack congito-google-dev failed to deploy (463s)
Environment: win32, node 16.14.2, framework 3.16.0 (local) 3.15.2v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: `docker run --rm -v C:/Users/we45-LT47/AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/d98982e5464ee25ad84f9e87694fcb7b74932dfab07a453cb894e394b2b00aa4_x86_64_slspyc:/var/task:z -v C:/Users/we45-LT47/AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/downloadCacheslspyc:/var/useDownloadCache:z -u 0 lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 python -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownloadCache` Exited with code 1 
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\we45-LT47\projects\serverless\congito-google\congito-google\node_modules\child-process-ext\spawn.js:38:8)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\we45-LT47\projects\serverless\congito-google\congito-google\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)

Running "serverless" from node_modules
PS C:\Users\we45-LT47\projects\serverless\congito-google\congito-google> serverless deploy
Running "serverless" from node_modules
```

this is the error i am getting while trying to deploy  . is this an issue of python or a configuration problem  , i am use the basic config as stated in the serverless-python-requirement documentation